# When click Image and show clicking Image in popup in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, popup

How to create, When click Image and show clicking Image in popup.

This is my code :-

```
echo "<td>"?><img src="<?php echo $this->getMediaUrl() .'brand'. $data->getImage(); ?>" width="100px" height="100px" class="click-header"></td>
```

**JS Code :-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($, modal) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            img: '$(".click-header").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));'
        };
        $(".click-header").on('click', function() {
            $("#header-mpdal").modal(options).modal('openModal');
        });
        // $('.modal-footer').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Out Put Show Blank :-

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

We are found the Solution.

```
---------HTML-------------------

    <div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
        <img class="popup-image" src=" " />
    </div>
--------- PHP ------------    
    echo "<td>"?><img src="<?php echo $this->getMediaUrl() .'brand'. $data->getImage(); ?>" width="100px"
        height="100px" class="click-header"></td>

-------- Script --------------    
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function($, modal) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $(".click-header").on('click', function() {
                console.log($(this).attr('src'));
                $(".popup-image").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
                //$("#header-mpdal").modal(options).modal('openModal');
            });
            $('.modal-footer').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**`OutPut :-`**

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code:**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendorName_ModuleName', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
                <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
        </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="show.image.in.popup"
                   template="VendorName_ModuleName::image_popup.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="VendorName_ModuleName::js/image_in_popup.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**image_popup.phtml**

```
<div id="show-image-popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <img class="popup-image" src=" " />
</div>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**image_in_popup.js**

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function($, modal) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#show-image-popup-modal'));
            $(".show-in-popup").on('click', function() {
                $(".popup-image").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
                $("#show-image-popup-modal").modal("openModal");
                $('.modal-footer').hide();
            });
        });
    });
```

After that run the below magento commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

> Now you can add the **show-in-popup** class to the image tag which you want to show in the popup.